# Getting crash in Facebook Audience network while showing ad

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-audience-network

I have integrated Facebook audience network to show ads,

Code:

```
if (fbInterstitialAd.isAdValid == YES) {
    [fbInterstitialAd showAdFromRootViewController:viewController];
}
```

but getting this crash while showing ad:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidOperationException', reason: 'showAdFromRootViewController may only be called once'
```

Note:

- While running on Native **iOS** it was working, but when I tried to run it on **Unity** then crashing.
- This thread didn't help me: https://twittercommunity.com/t/crash-in-showadfromrootviewcontroller/47005

Comment: Similar issue in banner showing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59062922/facebook-banner-ad-issue-in-unity/59198127#59198127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, FBInterstitialAd is limited to show only once. If an app is trying to show it more than once, the 'InvalidOperationException' will be throwed.

First, please add try/catch around the method '[fbInterstitialAd showAdFromRootViewController:viewController];' to avoid crash.

Second, to verify your integration and make sure the object 'fbInterstitialAd' is not showed more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will add try catch over there, but How can I make sure that 'fbInterstitialAd' is not showed more than once?
Is there any method fb providing for that?

Comment: The object `FBInterstitialAd` itself does not provide a method for checking right now. 
A local flag can be added for this. According to your code, the flag can be used as below:

`if (fbInterstitialAd.isAdValid == YES && isAlreadyViewed == FALSE) {
    [fbInterstitialAd showAdFromRootViewController:viewController];
    isAlreadyViewed = TRUE;
}`

Answer (score 2):

I do want to show interstitial ads more than once time too, so this is my way.

When interstitial ads did show, 'interstitialAdWillLogImpression' delegate will be call. I will create new interstitial ads at time.

```
func interstitialAdWillLogImpression(interstitialAd: FBInterstitialAd) {
    fbInterstitialAd = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "your_placement_id")
    fbInterstitialAd.delegate = self
    fbInterstitialAd.loadAd()
}
```