# Facebook Banner Ad Issue in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network

I am using the facebook audience network in Unity for advertisement.
I am currently facing an issue while showing facebook banner ads in unity.
Just when i call banner ad show call. Exception triggers:

> java.lang.illegalargumentexception: adsize at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.x.8h.(:18251)

Anybody knows how can I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using unity 19.2.x  version?

Comment: Can you please add more details like which version of Facebook SDK you're using ? It would be great if you can create a demo so that i can investigate the issue. Make sure you have added all jar files required for audiance network.

Comment: yes I am using 19.2.0 version

Comment: I am using the latest Audience network version to the date.
Also, I am using google mobile ads along with its play services. So when It resolved it includes all jar files. Moreover, It's working fine in IOS. The only issue came up in Android.

Comment: @FaisalImran Are you using Facebook banner ad in Unity?